# Find latest DATE in query WITHOUT using FETCH ONLY on ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT
  COD_USUARIO  COD_USUARIO3,
  FECHA,
  USR_APLICA,
  TABLA,
  CAMPO,
  decode(campo, 'PALABRA_PASO', '***********', valor_actual) VALOR_ACTUAL,
  decode(campo, 'PALABRA_PASO', '***********', valor_anterior) VALOR_ANTERIOR,
  TIPO_DML                           
FROM 
  PA_AUDITO_X_USUARIO
WHERE
  trunc(fecha) between '01-jun-2021' and '05-jul-2021'
  AND VALOR_ACTUAL = 'N'
ORDER BY 
  FECHA
```

Which returns something like this:

[image]

I want to return only the one with the LATEST date. I can easily do this with

```sql
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

but my custom tool (which copies Oracle Reports) will not return only one, but all of the rows. It's as if it doesn't recognize the `FETCH FIRST` command.

How can I do this?

I'm guessing I can use `MAX()` in some way, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm a little lost.  If you added a `fetch` clause you would get the *earliest* date.  Also what tool are you using that ignores the clause?

Comment: It's ordered by FECHA DESC (TYPO).

Comment: And I'm using JReportsBuilder

Comment: BTW, if your column FECHA is of type DATE, (as it _should_ be) then your clause "WHERE  trunc(fecha) between '01-jun-2021' and '05-jul-2021'" is tryin to compare a _string_ to a DATE, forcing oracle to perform an implied TO_DATE on '01-jun-2021' and '05-jul-2021'.  This only works if NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-mon-YYYY'.  You shouldn't depend on that.  Instead, use explicit TO_DATE functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can try another `SELECT` on top of that one and use the `ROWNUM = 1` to filter the first line.

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        COD_USUARIOCOD_USUARIO3,
        FECHA,
        USR_APLICA ,
        TABLA,
        CAMPO,
        decode(campo, 'PALABRA_PASO', '***********', valor_actual) VALOR_ACTUAL ,
        decode(campo, 'PALABRA_PASO', '***********', valor_anterior) VALOR_ANTERIOR,
        TIPO_DML
    FROM 
        PA_AUDITO_X_USUARIO
    WHERE 
        trunc(fecha) between '01-jun-2021' and '05-jul-2021'
        AND VALOR_ACTUAL = 'N'
    ORDER BY FECHA
) x
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help. If it works please mark it as answered :)

Comment: Actually the tool will not accept this either... My coworker who is sick with COVID told me it is probably solvable with MAX(), but I don't want to bother him too much as he's feeling pretty bad.

Comment: What can you change in the query? Can you add another column with SQL ? We can try that way also.
We can use MAX() or another function to solve that problem.

Comment: @Agustin About the tool not accepting, could it be related with the `SELECT *` ? If we change it to `SELECT` with the field list, would that help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the only option of MAX function, You can try below query -

```
SELECT 
        COD_USUARIOCOD_USUARIO3,
        MAX(FECHA),
        USR_APLICA ,
        TABLA,
        CAMPO,
        decode(campo, 'PALABRA_PASO', '***********', valor_actual) VALOR_ACTUAL ,
        decode(campo, 'PALABRA_PASO', '***********', valor_anterior) VALOR_ANTERIOR,
        TIPO_DML
    FROM 
        PA_AUDITO_X_USUARIO
    WHERE 
        trunc(fecha) between '01-jun-2021' and '05-jul-2021'
        AND VALOR_ACTUAL = 'N'
    GROUP BY COD_USUARIOCOD_USUARIO3,
        USR_APLICA,
        TABLA,
        CAMPO,
        valor_actual,
        valor_anterior,
        TIPO_DML
    ORDER BY FECHA
```

Comment: This gives the same results as the original query. What I was looking for was a way of limiting the results. Basically the same functionality as LIMIT and FETCH ONLY, both of which my tool does not apply for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by nesting a SELECT inside my WHERE clauses.

```
SELECT e.COD_EMPLEADO codigo,
       pa_nom_persona(e.COD_EMPLEADO) nombre,
       xo_desc_parametro('PO', 'CARGOS', e.COD_PUESTO) cargo,
       e.EM_F_RET fecha_retiro,
       p.COD_USUARIO usuario,
       p.FECHA fecha_inactivacion,
       p.USR_APLICA ejecutador,
       TO_DATE(p.FECHA, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE(e.EM_F_RET, 'DD-MM-YYYY') Diferencia_de_Inactivacion



FROM empleados e
       INNER JOIN PA_AUDITO_X_USUARIO p
       ON e.COD_EMPLEADO = PA_PKG_USUARIO.cod_persona(p.COD_USUARIO)

WHERE e.EM_F_RET IS NOT NULL
       AND CAMPO = 'EST_ACTIVO'
       AND VALOR_ACTUAL = 'N'
       AND p.COD_USUARIO = 'RBO'
       AND p.FECHA = (SELECT MAX(FECHA) FROM PA_AUDITO_X_USUARIO WHERE COD_USUARIO = p.COD_USUARIO AND CAMPO = p.CAMPO
                      AND VALOR_ACTUAL = VALOR_ACTUAL)
       
GROUP BY e.COD_EMPLEADO, pa_nom_persona(e.COD_EMPLEADO), xo_desc_parametro('PO', 'CARGOS', e.COD_PUESTO), e.EM_F_RET, 
                p.COD_USUARIO, p.FECHA, p.USR_APLICA, TO_DATE(p.FECHA, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - TO_DATE(e.EM_F_RET, 'DD-MM-YYYY')

ORDER BY fecha DESC
```